# Excluded row based on a another table cell value in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

student master
[image]
Feemaster 
[image]
I executed the query

```
SELECT f.standard,fee_type,fee_name,amount,ac_year FROM fee_master f, student_master s
where
s.standard=f.standard and
s.admission_no='21300';
```

I got resultset like
[image]

**But my need is**
if studnet_master.ac_year==**AC16** then **INITIAL FEE** should get removed from resultset or if studnet_master.ac_year==**!=AC16** then **ADMISSION FEE** should get removed from resultset

Can anyone please help me to sort out this....

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add two extra conditions to your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT f.standard, f.fee_type, f.fee_name, f.amount, s.ac_year
FROM fee_master f
INNER JOIN
student_master s
    ON s.standard = f.standard
WHERE s.admission_no = '21300' AND
    (s.ac_year != 'AC16' OR f.fee_name != 'INITIAL FEES') AND
    (s.ac_year = 'AC16' OR f.fee_name != 'ADMISSION FEES')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can put condition in and statement.
Query:-
SELECT f.standard,fee_type,fee_name,amount,ac_year FROM fee_master f, student_master s
where
s.standard=f.standard and
s.admission_no='21300' and
IF(s.ac_year = 'AC16',FEE_NAME != 'INITIAL FEES',FEE_NAME != 'ADMISSION FEES')
```